# How do I sort an array of different classes?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have two NSManagedObject classes "Person" and "Animal". Both classes have a "name" property. How can I sort them alphabetically into a single array?

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name:String?
    @NSManaged var occupation:String?
}

class Animal: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name:String?
    @NSManaged var breed:String?
}

//This array is filled with both people and animal objects from my database
var peopleAndAnimals = [NSManagedObject]() 

peopleAndAnimals.sort(//I want to sort alphabetically by name here)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
peopleAndAnimals.sortInPlace {
    if let name1 = $0.valueForKey("name") as? String,
           name2 = $1.valueForKey("name") as? String {
        return name1 < name2
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using NSSortDescriptor, that's how I usually alphabetize arrays. Here's the NSHipster page for it http://nshipster.com/nssortdescriptor/.